# Javascript Reddit Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, reddit

Some days ago I've written JavaScript bot for reddit. All it does is replacing not well-formatted gfycat URLs. I would love to hear feedback about this code!

```
const chalk = require('chalk')
const Snoowrap = require('snoowrap')
const async = require('async')

console.log(chalk.cyan.bold('GfycatDetailsConvert is booting up...'))

let lastChecked

require('dotenv').config()

if (typeof process.env.REDDIT_USERAGENT === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error('Please fill your .env file. For more information, go here: https://github.com/ImJustToNy/GfycatDetailsConvert')
}

const r = new Snoowrap({
  userAgent: process.env.REDDIT_USERAGENT,
  clientId: process.env.REDDIT_CLIENTID,
  clientSecret: process.env.REDDIT_CLIENTSECRET,
  username: process.env.REDDIT_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.REDDIT_PASSWORD
})

r.config({
  requestDelay: 2000,
  continueAfterRatelimitError: true,
  maxRetryAttempts: 5,
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production'
})

setInterval(() => {
  r.getNew('all', {
    before: lastChecked,
    show: 'all',
    amount: 1000
  }).then(posts => {
    if (posts.length > 0) {
      lastChecked = posts[0].name

      async.every(posts, (post, callback) => {
        if (post.domain === 'gfycat.com' && /(\/[a-z][a-z])?\/gifs\/detail/g.test(post.url)) {
          post.fetch().comments.map(comment => comment.author.name).then(participants => {
            callback(null, true)
            if (!participants.includes(process.env.REDDIT_USERNAME)) {
              console.log(chalk.red(chalk.bold('Found new post: ') + post.title + ' [/r/' + post.subreddit.display_name + ']'))

              post.reply('[Proper Gfycat URL](' + post.url.replace(/(\/[a-z][a-z])?\/gifs\/detail/g, '') + ') \n\n' + '^^I\'m ^^just ^^a ^^bot, ^^bleep, ^^bloop. [^^[Why?]](https://gist.github.com/ImJustToNy/cb3457e36f22123eb93864f0af639da3) [^^[Source ^^code]](https://github.com/ImJustToNy/GfycatDetailsConvert)')
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `post.fetch().comments.map(...).then(...)` is correct? Looking at the documentation, it looks like it should be `post.fetch().then(...). ...` and the documentation is unclear how to access the `comments` from there.

Comment: Ah, I figured out the documentation after looking at the source. It should be `post.fetch().then(post => post.comments.map(...)).then(...)`

Comment: Oh, double correction, I just read the notice about proxy support [when accessing an unknown property](https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/snoowrap/blob/master/src/objects/RedditContent.js#L33-L34). TL;DR what's shown is correct, but inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, it gets the job done, but your code (especially the area I'd refer to as "pyramid code"), could use a little more organization and clarity.

Your `if` statement could be a little more concise, and, at the same time, more canonical about what it's actually there for:

```
if (!('REDDIT_USERAGENT' in process.env)) {
  ...
}
```

You can write concise code without using cryptic variable names. Change `r` to something more meaningful like `robot` or even just `bot`.

One way to resolve pyramid code is to look for places where your logic can be decoupled or flattened. While it's possible to continue to use the `async` dependency in order to achieve this, it's probably much easier to just use `async/await` since you're already using promises anyway. This will also give you an opportunity to get rid of your global variable `lastChecked`:

```
function matchesRequirements (post) {
  return post.domain === 'gfycat.com' && /(\/[a-z][a-z])?\/gifs\/detail/g.test(post.url)
}

async function tryReply (post) {
  const { comments, subreddit, title, url } = await post.fetch()
  const participants = comments.map(comment => comment.author.name)

  if (!participants.includes(process.env.REDDIT_USERNAME)) {
    console.log(chalk.red(`${chalk.bold('Found new post:')} ${title} [/r/${subreddit.display_name}]`))

    const proper = url.replace(/(\/[a-z][a-z])?\/gifs\/detail/g, '')
    const reason = 'https://gist.github.com/ImJustToNy/cb3457e36f22123eb93864f0af639da3'
    const source = 'https://github.com/ImJustToNy/GfycatDetailsConvert'

    const text = `[Proper Gfycat URL](${proper}) \n\n^^I'm ^^just ^^a ^^bot, ^^bleep, ^^bloop. [^^[Why?]](${reason}) [^^[Source ^^code]](${source})`

    return post.reply(text)
  }
}

async function pollNewPosts () {
  let lastChecked

  while (true) {
    const posts = await bot.getNew('all', {
      before: lastChecked,
      show: 'all',
      amount: 1000
    })

    if (posts.length > 0) {
      lastChecked = posts[0].name
    }

    await Promise.all(posts
      .filter(matchesRequirements)
      .map(tryReply)
    )

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))
  }
}

pollNewPosts()
```

One of the things in this rewrite to flatten your pyramid code, I changed the order in which `.fetch()` is called, because the way your code accessed the `comments` property [relied on the usage of a proxy](https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/snoowrap/blob/master/src/objects/RedditContent.js#L33-L34) get trap in order to work properly, which is both unnecessary and inefficient.

Lastly, I cleaned up your generated text to break it up into a few lines, otherwise it's quite unreadable. You might consider storing that text to an external template file using a minimal template engine (possibly written yourself just for this specific case) in order to avoid hard-coding it in here.

Comment: Have you tested this? I believe the result from `fetch` needs to call `.json()` and `await` that?

Comment: @kamoroso94 no I haven't

Comment: @kamoroso94 I've tested it. It works. 
@PatrickRoberts Roberts I have 2 questions. First, do we really need that `fetch()`? If it lazy-loads everything it wants, maybe we can remove it? And second, I think you shouldn't wrap that much of a code in single `if(participants.includes[...])`, instead, why don't just do `if(!participants.includes[...]) return`?

Comment: The point about using the `fetch()` is to avoid forcing the program to depend on `Proxy()`, which is very inefficient. As for your second point, that is a very good suggestion, as it reduces the complexity of `tryReply()`. I didn't intentionally avoid doing that, it just didn't occur to me the first time around since there were a few larger readability issues to deal with first.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for all of your advices! I've rewritten some parts of this project! I really appreciate your help! If you would like to, you can check it out here: https://github.com/ImJustToNy/GfycatDetailsConvert

Comment: @ToNy nice! I see you even set up a small templating engine as I recommended, that looks very good. Just one comment about that though, I saw you have `require(path.join(__dirname, '/lib/showError.js'))`, that (and other similar includes) can be replaced with `require('./lib/showError.js')`, you don't need the absolute path to it. In addition, a `.js` or a `.json` file can have its extension omitted, so simply calling `require('./lib/showError')` would work as well.